# How to log username of the user trying to stop a service in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, service

I have made the service to not stop when using services.msc or cmd or task manager by changing descriptors of the service and restricting access, but I want to log details of user who tries to stop the service using any methods. So, is there any way I can log user details ?
I have wrote a GoLang code for service to continuously log user details but it does not log when there is an attempt to stop the service.
My Go function for the service is:

```
func UserDetails() {
    currentUser, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }
    sysname := currentUser.Name
    log.Printf("%s", sysname)

    data := []byte(sysname)

    erro := ioutil.WriteFile("UserDetails.txt", data, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(erro)
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: 1) This is not a question about programming in Go; it's plain Win32 API stuff. 2) It's futile to query the "current user": even single-user Windows flavors (NT-kernel based and beyond) are muli-user in their core, and your service can be stopped by a process which runs in the context of a user account which has no interactive session. On server-class Windows, a user can be logged in through WTS (or even SSH—on contemporary Windows). `os/user.Current()` returns the user who started the process executing _this_ call, which is useless in the case being discussed.

Comment: Given that the signature of the [`HandlerEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lphandler_function_ex) function called by the SCM when the service which has registered that control callback is "sent" a control signal (such as an order to stop) does not appear as being passed any information about who initiated the action. Hence your best bet (barring installing some deep kernel hooks akin to those used by A/V software) is to use the WTS to periodically query the list of interactive sessions and _guess_ who _might have_ stopped the service…

Comment: …which is still, mildly put, ineffective, because it's inherently racy and cannot track a determined evil user: if the user has permissions to mess with the service, they could surely install their own, which would stop yours or install a cron job which would do the same etc—all this when the user might be logged off.

Comment: You could also explore another approach: I woud not be surprised if the fact that someone had used (any) system UI to SCM to stop a service is logged through the usual Windows Event Log. So you could probably either try to analyze the log "postmortem" or install a monitoring callback in your service to try to get that information. Still, I conjure that logging of such information naturally races with the delivery of the control signals to the service, so nothing guarantees that the relevan log record would appear before the service receives the matching signal, or even in a reasonably short…

Comment: …time frame after that. But at least you could probably research that.

Comment: ACLs supports alert ACEs that triggers logging to the security log.